# Facebook Android SDK 3.5.2 callback cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, facebook, callback

I'm following this Facebook tutorial: [Using the Share Dialog on Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/).

I have imported the Facebook Android SDK 3.5.2 and added code snippets from the tutorial to use a [Share a link function](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/#sharelink).

The problem is that Eclipse shows error: "Callback cannot be resolved to a variable". As I'm new to this I need some help resolving this error and some guidance how to implement needed callback.

Comment: did you import facebook Session?

Comment: @Droid Thanks for the tip. But now I'm getting this error: "Argument applicationID cannot be null". I have defined <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.Applicationid" android:value="@string/app_id" /> in AndroidManifest.xml. I also have app_id set in strings.xml. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: are you defing the meta-data under the application tag?

Comment: is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use meta-data tag as :

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            >
        <activity>
        ................
        ................
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    </application>
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I used a small letter "i" in "ApplicationID". It worked fine in previouse Facbook SDK 3.0 when I used it to measure mobile install ads.